# upgrading to laravel 5.1 - removing guard from base controller gives error

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

I'm upgrading my app to laravel 5.1 following the upgrade guide in the official docs. It says for authentication

> you no longer need to pass the Guard and Registrar instances to the base constructor. You can remove these dependencies entirely from your controller's constructor.

But after removing this from base constructor in AuthController when i try to visit the login page below error is shown

```
ErrorException in AuthController.php line 41:
Undefined variable: auth
```

what i'm doing wrong??

Comment: You must have also deleted some code where you define an $auth variable.  All you need to delete is `use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;` and `use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Registrar;`.

Comment: i thought it says to remove them from constructor method like this __constructor(),isn't that's what its say?

Comment: if i delete `use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;` and `use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Registrar;` & keep instance in constructor method  then this error is shown `Trait 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers' not found`

Comment: This is the link to the new AuthController.php  - https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php  
If you have any custom changes, I would just add them to this file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your constructor probably still mentions the following:

```
//$this->auth = $auth;
//$this->registrar = $registrar;
```

Just comment these two lines.